# how make a listview item like controlgroup?

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-listview

I want to show my data like this https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/12173475/sample.png ,
a bit like controlgroup, but controlgroup not seem to merge two labels,
how can I do?

This is my code (temporarily), but I hope there is a line between those(like controlgroup).

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
   <li>
       <div>name</div>
       <div class="ui-li-aside">name1</div>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by modifying CSS.

**HTML**

```
<ul class='my_list' data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
   <li>
       <div>name</div>
       <div class="ui-li-aside">name1</div>
   </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.my_list li{
    padding:0px !important;
}
.my_list li div{
    padding:10px;
}
.my_list li div:nth-child(2){
    width:10%;
    border-right:1px solid #ccc;
}
.my_list li .ui-li-aside{
    margin:0px;
}
```

here is Demo [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jJYmt/374/)